# None to not be defaulted in picklist

Tags: visualforce, picklist

On a visualforce Page..
I have called a picklist Field
Is there a way to get rid of -- None -- in picklist and replace it with "Please Select...."

None is always shown when we give the picklist field

Comment: I think you can consider JQUERY for this task. You can select all the select option and replace the values.

Comment: Not sure how to use Jquery

Answer (score 2):

Well have a look at the below example that I did. This basically doesn't need any change on the controller and uses a simple script to alter the text

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
    <script>
        $j = jQuery.noConflict();

        $j(function(){
            replacePickVals();
        });

        function replacePickVals(){
            $j('option').filter(function () { return $j(this).html() == "--None--"; }).html('Please Select....');
        }
    </script>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >

                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Industry}" onchange="replacePickVals();"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

To make this work in your page just copy the script content into your page including refrence to jquery.

Comment: This is working well.. but happens only on page load.. if i have a dependent picklist then it shows.. none and also i can view none as one of the options in picklist

Comment: I have update the answer to accommodate on demand calling of the function. Just call the function "replacePickVals" when you change the controlling field.

Comment: Thanks Avidev.. it worked charms...I had onchnge event rendering and calling action functions . So i gave it as oncomplete event of action function

Comment: Hey Avidev... The dependent picklist initially shows None and it shows Please Select only when it becomes active.. Can we have the please Select  shown also when picklist field is disabled

Answer (score 0):

In the field setup you need to add "Please Select" as another option and then  make as a default  other  if you want a little advanced functionality  try the below code

```
  String  ObjectApi_name = 'your object name'
     Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(ObjectApi_name);//From the Object Api name retrieving the SObject
        Sobject Object_name = targetType.newSObject();
      Schema.sObjectType sobject_type = Object_name.getSObjectType(); //grab the sobject that was passed
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobject_describe = sobject_type.getDescribe(); //describe the sobject
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> field_map = sobject_describe.fields.getMap(); //get a map of fields for the passed sobject
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = field_map.get(Field_name).getDescribe().getPickListValues(); //grab the list of picklist values for the passed field on the sobject
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : pick_list_values) { //for all values in the picklist list
          lstPickvals.add(a.getValue());//add the value  to our final list


}
```

after getting the picklist entries add please select entry to this

Comment: I tried first approach.. but i am getting none as one of the picklist values in the dropdown... .

Comment: Did you make the Please Select as default vslue?

Comment: Yes.. 
i did that